# Extending LTE internet from remote location to building on same property

Tags: routing, wireless, fiber

This question may be a bit off-topic for this forum, but I am hoping there are enough experts to take a stab at it anyway.

My office is in a rural-ish location - I can only get DSL at 3 Mbps from Verizon.

Town-wide fiber is years off at best.

My ATT iPhone can get 3 bars of LTE with 50 Mbps up/down speeds at a point 800 feet from my office (but still on the same property which I own). *Edit: only a single bar of 4G available in the office.*

My question is: What options do I have for receiving that signal, and then repeating/amplifying it, and then getting it back to my office either via wireless repeater, or a buried fiber cable, or very long Cat5/6 cable?

Should I be trying to forward the LTE signal with an LTE booster (which I don't think will work), or should I grab the LTE signal, plug it into an ethernet router/switch, and send it back to my office via either wireless antennas or a buried fiber cable?

I an open to spending a few thousand $$ to get this working, but I'd like to figure out what options I have and the best way to proceed.

Comment: Am I to assume you don't get a usable LTE signal in your office?  BTW, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: right, 1 bar of 4G only

Comment: and if specific product recommendations are OT, then a basic configuration recommendation would suffice - I can research brands.

Comment: I would first try an LTE modem with a better antenna, before I'd start burying cable.

Comment: Your carrier should have some options.

Comment: and maybe try it on the roof (subject to permissions and safety of course)

Comment: ALready tried one of these on the roof: http://www.wilsonsignalbooster.com/ - their top-of-the-line model. Didn't work - I really need to pickup the signal 800 feet away from the building, not at the building.

Comment: Don't use a signal booster.  Get an LTE router (your carrier should be able to offer you one, or at least tell you what kinds are compatible with their network).  Cisco makes several models as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need line of sight to wirelessly *bridge* your LTE connection from the good spot to your office.  You need power and a NEMA enclosure to house your 4g LTE router.  You may be able to WiFi bridge with the same router or you may need a dedicated WiFi bridge in that NEMA enclosure as well.

In the office, you need a 2nd WiFi bridge to talk to the good spot / NEMA enclosure.  This bridge should be a dual mode device that supports bridging and AP modes simultaneously.

See [Cisco's 801](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/routers/810-integrated-services-routers-isr/model.html), for example.  Find a Cisco reseller in your area or contact me if you need help.

You'll probably have to spend a couple of grand to get the initial setup going, then you'll need to pay AT&T for the monthly 4G LTE service.  The WiFi bridges and office AP is a 1 time cost.

You can WiFi bridge many many miles with line of sight, so bridging distance won't be an issue assuming line of sight.

Comment: The vast majority of "WiFi Bridge" products (suitable for this sort of application) do not need to be put in a weatherproof enclosure. They are already outdoor packaged from the factory, and merely need to be connected with the correct side pointing down so that any condensation will drain.